# Placing top elements alongside with overset

Tags: equations, overset

I would like to display the equation representing `$\varepsilon$` with diacritic mark `$\circ$`, with an apex simbol `t` and a pedex `s`. In particular, I would like that `t` is aligned on top of `$\varepsilon$`, and that `$\circ$` is only put on top of `$\varepsilon$`, but not over both `$\varepsilon$` and `t`. I tried to use the following solutions, but both of them did not satisfy me:

- `$\overset{\circ}{\varepsilon^t_s}$`, the `$\circ$` is put between `$\varepsilon$` and `$t$`:

  [image]
- `$\overset{\circ}{\varepsilon}^t_s$`, `$t$` is put on top of `$\circ$`:

  [image]

Is there an intermediate solution?

Comment: `\mathring{\varepsilon}^{t}_{s}`

Comment: That's it, I didn't know `\mathring` existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for `\mathring`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\mathring{\varepsilon}_{s}^{t}$

\end{document}
```

[image]